# Sum of an infinite series involving the normal cdf and pdf

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, gaussian-integral

I'm struggling with the two following infinite series:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^2[(i+1)\Phi(i+1)-2i\Phi(i)+(i-1)\Phi(i-1)]
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^2[\phi(i+1)-2\phi(i)+(i-1)\phi(i-1)]
$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $\phi(\cdot)$ are the cdf and the pdf of a standard normal random variable. The former sum should be equal to $-5/12$, the latter $+1$, but I cannot prove it mathematically.
Any help?